# WSO2 - What is the right way to include a java class as part of the project

Tags: java, wso2

I want to add a POJO to my WSO2 project which is the java type of a fact that I am passing as input to the Rule Mediator. At the moment I have the class added to a custom mediator project. But what is the correct way to do this?

I'm using integration studio 7.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class mediator to inject the POJO into your sequence. Note that you'll have to extend the `AbstractMediator` class in order to do this. Refer to this documentation on [class mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/class-Mediator/) for more information.

Comment: Yes agreed that this can be done but this doesn't feel like the right way :)

Comment: This is the recommended way. If you want to convert your java class into a more generic mediator then that can be converted into a custom mediator, but even this approach is totally fine.

Comment: But the idea is not to use my java class as a mediator.. I want to use a custom type.. in rule mediator..